# Perl: search for a match multiple times in a file

Tags: regex, perl

In my perl script, I opened a file and search for a string. It was successful. But when I search for the same string again right after that search, it seems the script starts searching from where it was until the end of the file, and hence it is not able to find the match any more. My code is something like:

```
open ( INFILE, "./input.txt")

for($i=0; $i < 3； $i++){

    print "i = $i\n";
    $found = 0;

    while (! $found && ($line = <INFILE>)){
        if ( $line ~/string/ ）{
           print "found!\n";
           $found = 1;
        }
        else{
           print "not found!\n";
        }
    }
}

close (INFILE);
```

**The input.txt file:**

```
string
random2
random2
```

**I was expecting the output to be:**

```
i = 0
found!
i = 1
found!
i = 2 
found!
```

**but it turns out to be:**

```
i = 0
found!
i = 1
not found!
not found!
i = 2
```

Can anyone help me with this. I just started learning perl.

Comment: Why would you expect that code to print 'found!' when `string` only matches on the first line of your file?

Comment: @kjprice: Since I used a 'for' loop in the code, I am expecting in each iteration, it will start all over from the beginning of the input file and find the match. Isn't correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because when you read file in perl it will mark the last position you read in file so it won't read it again, in your case you read the whole file so you marked to the end of file and you need to reset position by doing a seek to the beginning again

```
for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++ ){
    seek(INFILE,0,0);
    #...
```

This will reset filehandle to the start again see [perl seek tut](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

Since you're starting learning perl then here's a general instructions you may use

- always use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)
- use the three-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

  ```
  open ( my $INFILE, "<", "./input.txt");
  ```
- use [**my**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) with every variable for localization

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [binding operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) (`=~`) for regular expression matching.
Change:

```
if ($line = ~/string/ ）{
```

to:

```
if ($line =~ /string/ ）{
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have lies in the conditional part of `while (! $found && ($line = <INFILE>))`

The `$line = <INFILE>` **actually assigns the complete contents of the file to `$line`**. *It does **NOT** assign line by line*. By extension, your loop runs only once.

Possible solutions to fix this are:

- You should change the loop to `for my $line (<INFILE>)` to read the file line by line, and separate the $found into an inner `if($found)`.
- Utilize the outer `for` loop for your work (the `while` is unnecessary`:

  ```
  open ( INFILE, "./input.txt")

  my @line=<INFILE>;
  for($i=0; $i < scalar @line； $i++) {
      print "i = $i\n";
      if ( $line[$i] =~ /string/ ）{
          print "found!\n";
      } else {
          print "not found!\n";
      }
  }

  close (INFILE);
  ```

The point in the other answers about Perl good practices apply as usual.